# What elements do I need to create a smooth multi cheese slope ramp?

Tags: building

I love cheese slopes, but I am having issues when I try to produce a smooth gradient using several in succession. I end up with a gentle saw tooth effect at each junction. What combination of elements do I require to get the smooth appearance I'm trying to achieve?

[image: Offsets with cheese slopes]

Comment: Do you have a picture of what you have so far?

Comment: I can add one tomorrow. Right now it's past my bedtime. :)

Comment: I think I can see the problem, I'll add a temporary render for now ;)

Comment: From that pic it seems like not even a half-plate resolution will be perfect, but better. A quarter-plate offset might do the trick.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To create a smooth surface with cheese slopes they must be offset by one-half plate in height. There are several techniques to do this. Here is one using the common "headlight" brick. It has the advantage of being extendable to nearly any length.

[image]

Comment: Ahah! I knew Erling bricks were involved, but didn't have the time to dig deep enough ;)

Answer (score 10):

This would be a way but other techniques may suit you as well.

[image: One among many ways to make smooth cheese slope ramps]

Comment: Looks good, but how long of a slope could you make like this?